# how to customize Date in jackson serialization , @JsonSerialize not working

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jersey-2.0, jackson-databind

i want to change the date format in a json that is delivered by a java rest webservice, that is because the json have the dates like this: *2019-05-23T06:00:00Z[UTC]*  ,   so the client confuse the  *[UTC]* with an array,  because of the '[' and  ']'

im using glassfish 5 ,jax-rs , jackson 2.9.4 databind,
        .    i have tried to use **@JsonSerialize(using = CustomXSerializer.class)**  in the model object and didn work,  also **@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy",timezone="CET")** in the Date property in the model object but again didnt work, its always showing [UTC]

my code:

```
package api;
import model.people;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/helloworld")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloWorldRest {

  @GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public people sayHello() {

    people p=new people("pepe", "27",new Date());
    return p;

  }
}
```

the model object:

```
public class people {
    private String nombre;
    private String edad;
       @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy",timezone="CET")
    public Date d;
    public people(String pNombre,String pEdad,Date pD)
    { nombre=pNombre;
        edad=pEdad;
        d=pD;
    }
.
.
//getters and setters
```

pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

is there any way to change the format if the Date seralization in one spot for all the model objects? i would prefer that instead of creating custom serializer for each model object , thanks in advance

Comment: yes i tried , but didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found what my problem was, i needed to register jackson  as the json provider in jersey , so it can be registered in the web.xml like this

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and using the dependency at the pom like this:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.x</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I've been driven nuts over this and this worked for me. I've now come to realize Glassfish uses another provider by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I normally use a `@Provider` to customize dates.

```
@Provider
public class AppObjectMapper implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    static {
        // .. other configuration for Jackson Object Mapper.
        MAPPER.setDateFormat(df);
    }

    public AppObjectMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return MAPPER;
    }
}
```

Comment: i try it, but didnt work , still displaying the [UTC] format, ......sorry im kind of new in jackson ,  maybe i am missing something, where should the **AppObjectMapper** class be?  in some specific package or folder? ,