# In Spite of using Jackson for JSON, the code uses eclipse's yasson parser

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, payara

I am working on Restful Application to Run on Payara 5. In POM, even if I specify the Jackson parser, during the runtime, I continue to see Eclipse yasson.

I know Payara 5 comes with yasson parser for JSON, but given the reputation of Jackson, I want to give it a go.

Jackson dependencies in POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make changes in web.xml to use Jackson instead

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.jsonFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>JacksonFeature</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In the compiled sources i.e. the web app in the target folder generated by Maven,
I see all the Jackson jars in it (sorry can't attach the snapshot here.)

I expect a JSON message coming out of the Restful application, but all I see is this message on console:

```
Generating incomplete JSON|#]

java.lang.StackOverflowError

java.lang.StackOverflowError

at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.
 DefaultSerializers.findByCondition(DefaultSerializers.java:130)
```

Well, I am aware there are two issues here and the first one is the "StackOverflowError". However, my priority right now is to fix the Jackson-Yasson issues. So would be grateful, if any one can help.

Comment: i guees this might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296558/how-to-customize-date-in-jackson-serialization-jsonserialize-not-working